# python popen unexpected EOF in subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, stdin

I am trying to pass a passphrase/password into a subprocess, however the subprocess complains that there is an unexpected EOF. In my particular case I am trying to decrypt a hard drive with udisksctl. Here is my attempt followed by the error.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

mykey='password'

p = Popen(['udisksctl', 'unlock', '-b', '/dev/sdb1'], stdin=PIPE)
p.stdin.write(mykey+"\n");
p.stdin.close()
```

Error: `** (udisksctl unlock:16450): ERROR **: Unexpected EOF while reading from controlling terminal.`

Thanks for the help

Notes:

- Python version: 2.7.3
- OS: Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit
- The end program won't store the password as plain text. It will be read from the gnome-keyring.

Edit:

Thanks to tdelaney I got my program to work.

```
import pexpect

drive = '/dev/sdb1'
mykey = 'password'

child = pexpect.spawn('udisksctl unlock -b ' + drive)
child.expect('Passphrase:')
child.sendline(mykey)
i = child.expect(['Unlocked ' + drive + ' as ','already unlocked as ', pexpect.EOF])
child.close()

if (i > 1) :  sys.exit('Could not unlock ' + drive)

dev=(child.readline())[:-2]
if (i == 0) : dev = dev[:-1]
print 'Device =', dev
```

Comment: Did you try to *not* close `stdin`?

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes I did try that. I added the `p.stdin.close()` line hoping it would fix the problem. It did not.

Comment: @shockburner several reviewers rejected your addition to my answer but I think it would be fine to add your solution to your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux processes that ask for passwords typically behave oddly when not called from a terminal session. Use the python pexpect module instead of popen or check to see if the program offers a different way to pass in passwords.